# Aggregation $avg for node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

This is my current $avg.

```
db.contact.aggregate([{$group: {_id: "$machine_Id", AvgTemp: {$avg: "$air_Temp.air_Temp"}}},
    {$project: {_id: 0, machine_Id: '$_id', AvgTemp: 1}}],function(err, meibanlist) {
  if( err || !meibanlist ) console.log("Record not found");
  else meibanlist.forEach (function(machine_Id){
    console.log(machine_Id);
  });
});
```

the output was this:

```
{ AvgTemp: 0, machine_Id: 346 }
{ AvgTemp: 0, machine_Id: 470 }
{ AvgTemp: 0, machine_Id: 917 }
{ AvgTemp: 0, machine_Id: 167 }
{ AvgTemp: 0, machine_Id: 4 }
```

desired answer:

```
(machine_Id: 200, AvgTemp:25)
```

Where only one output is shown which is the average temperature of all the machine id put together. 
like i have 1000 air_temp temperatures. But i wanna get the average air_temp. with the machine id also instead of them printing the whole 1000 data.

Comment: Your projection should be {$project: {_id: 0, machine_Id: '$_id', AvgTemp: "$AvgTemp"}}

Comment: your code was giving me the one above the desired answer instead of my desired answer though